# Duplicate matrix to form list

Tags: r, matrix

a is a matrix.

```
a<-matrix(c(2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1),6)
```

I want to duplicate matrix "a" 3 times to form a list.

I have tried:

```
as.list(rep(a,3))
```

but it doesn't work.
My expected result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    1    2
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    2
[5,]    1    2    1    1
[6,]    2    1    2    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    1    2
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    2
[5,]    1    2    1    1
[6,]    2    1    2    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    1    2
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    2
[5,]    1    2    1    1
[6,]    2    1    2    1
```

Comment: Also `replicate(3, a, simplify = FALSE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rep` returns the same type it receives, so if you pass it a numeric matrix, it's going to try to return a numeric vector of some sort–not a list. The solution, though, is simple: if you want a list, pass it a list:

```
rep(list(a), 3)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    1    1    2
# [2,]    2    2    1    2
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    1    2
# [5,]    1    2    1    1
# [6,]    2    1    2    1
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    1    1    2
# [2,]    2    2    1    2
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    1    2
# [5,]    1    2    1    1
# [6,]    2    1    2    1
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    1    1    2
# [2,]    2    2    1    2
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    1    2
# [5,]    1    2    1    1
# [6,]    2    1    2    1
```

Comment: That's great! So it is!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using lapply:

```
lapply(1:3, function(i) a)
```

Benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)

a <- matrix(c(2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1),6)

microbenchmark(
  replicate(3, a, simplify = FALSE),
  rep(list(a), 3),
  lapply(1:3, function(i) a),
  times = 10000)


# Unit: nanoseconds
#                               expr  min   lq      mean median   uq     max neval cld
#  replicate(3, a, simplify = FALSE) 5987 7127 8044.9371   7413 7983 1150921 10000   c
#                    rep(list(a), 3)    0  285  396.2066    285  570   15395 10000 a  
#         lapply(1:3, function(i) a) 1995 2566 3013.6994   2851 3136 1290902 10000  b
```