# Vectorization from different dimensional arrays in R

Tags: r, optimization, vectorization, compiler-optimization

```
for(i in 1:1111){
for(j in 1:2222){
for(k in 1:3333){

      y[i, j, k] <- a[i] + b[j, k] 
}
}
}
```

where `a[ ], b[, ], y[ , , ]` is arrays.

This code take a long time, so I want to vectorization or any treatment to be more faster code.

Someone have any idea to make the code faster.

One way to solve, I am not sure, but by adjusting the index by replicating the arrays, it goes well ?

see for replication:

[Replicating 2 dimensional matrix to create a 3 dimensional array (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951663/replicating-2-dimensional-matrix-to-create-a-3-dimensional-array-in-r)

I am not sure array format make code faster.

If dimensions of arrays `a,b,y`  have same, then the code will simplify by

```
y <-a+b
```

and this seems faster code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler than what it seems. Just get rid of the two inner loops.
I have written the solution in the form of function for tests sake.

```
f1 <- function(m, n, o){
  a <- seq_len(m)
  b <- matrix(1:(n*o), nrow = n)
  y <- array(0, dim = c(m, n, o))
  for(i in seq_len(m)){
    for(j in seq_len(n)){
      for(k in seq_len(o)){
        y[i, j, k] <- a[i] + b[j, k] 
      }
    }
  }
  y
}

f2 <- function(m, n, o){
  a <- seq_len(m)
  b <- matrix(1:(n*o), nrow = n)
  y <- array(0, dim = c(m, n, o))
  for(i in seq_len(m)){
    y[i, , ] <- a[i] + b
  }
  y
}

m <- 11
n <- 22
o <- 33

y <- f1(m, n, o)
z <- f2(m, n, o)

identical(y, z)
#[1] TRUE
```

Now test the performance.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(m, n, o),
  f2 = f2(m, n, o)
)

mb
autoplot(mb)
```

Comment: Your code was very easy to understand thanks to your plain explanation and great !! Please let me use your great code in my developing R package. Thank you !!

Comment: @CamfordOxbridge Feel free to use it anyway you want. Glad it helps.